# ember-leaflet: how to refresh component data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, leaflet

I'm using [ember-leaflet](https://github.com/gabesmed/ember-leaflet) to display Leaflet maps in my Ember application. In my case, the map is used to display an appointment location. The user selects an appointment from a list and the corresponding appointment details (including the map) are then displayed.

When an appointment is selected, the details are passed to a component, which contains the map. Unfortunately, after the user selects an appointment and then another is selected, the coordinates on the map do not change. However, outputting the coordinates using Handlebars, I can in fact see that the different coordinates are being passed. That leads me to believe that the map needs to be "refreshed" somehow in order for the new coordinates to be displayed on the map.

I use the component like so: `{{ember-leaflet geoJSON=geoJSON}}` where `geoJSON` is a string containing the location data.

My component is as follows:

```
// components/leaflet-map.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import ENV from '../config/environment';

import EmberLeafletComponent from 'ember-leaflet/components/leaflet-map';
import MarkerCollectionLayer from 'ember-leaflet/layers/marker-collection';
import TileLayer from 'ember-leaflet/layers/tile';

L.Icon.Default.imagePath = '/images/leaflet';

export default EmberLeafletComponent.extend({

  center: Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.get('coordinates');
  }),

  /////////////////////////////////////
  // PROPERTIES
  /////////////////////////////////////

  geoJSON: null,

  /////////////////////////////////////
  // COMPUTED PROPERTIES
  /////////////////////////////////////

  childLayers: Ember.computed('coordinates', function() {

    return [
      TileLayer.extend({
        tileUrl: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}',
        options: {
          id: 'XXXXXXX',
          accessToken: ENV.APP.MAPBOX_KEY
        }
      }),
      MarkerCollectionLayer.extend({
        content: [{ location: this.get('coordinates') }]
      })
    ];
  }),

  coordinates: Ember.computed('geoJSON', function() {

    if (this.get('geoJSON')) {

      const coordinates = JSON.parse(this.get('geoJSON')).coordinates;

      if (coordinates) {
        return L.latLng(coordinates[1], coordinates[0]);
      }
    }

    return null;
  }),
});
```

When setting a breakpoint, it appears that `childLayers` and `coordinates` are only being called once regardless of which appointment is selected by the user. I've considered setting up an observer to observe the `geoJSON` property, but it seems overkill.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!